# Uninstall Application by a Single Click Android

Tags: android, uninstallation

Please help me to clear my doubt. I develop an application that performs uninstall applications. I use the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+appname));

    startActivity(intent);
```

But it will show the uninstall window(default) that the user made click "yes" to uninstall and "ok".
I need to make that process by simply clicking one button in my application. That is no need to view the uninstall window. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Installer and Uninstaller are under OS control. You can't modify them.

Comment: Ok. Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Android -- the user still has to confirm that the application is being uninstalled, which is by design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this only by modifying the android source and building it. Its not possible with an app.